# Passing stock price from Excel to Python with text file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From excel VBA I write stock price to text file `stock.txt` every price update, only if the file doesn't exist, if file `stock.txt` exists, I wait until python will delete that file to write new data in it.

From Python I use `df=pd.read_csv ("stock.txt")` to
read stock price
and then
`os.remove("stock.txt")` to delete the file.

Here some times I'm getting `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'stock.txt'`.

What I want is to continue my python program even if an error reading or delete files occurs.

Maybe there is a better way to pass data from excel to python.
Price refreshes very fast, sometimes 3 times a second.

Comment: The usual way to handle errors like this in Python is to put the code that might fail inside a `try`/`except` and ignore them when they occur (by putting only `pass` in the `except:` clause)

Comment: cut out the txt file and use [pd.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: will pd.read_excel() work on open excel file?